# Rails- redirect_to carrying over unwanted id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, url-routing

I am trying to redirect from a show action to a custom collection action, but the id param is being carried over, causing the routing to fail.  A minimal example:

routes.rb:

```
resources :first_models, only: [:show]

resources :second_models do
  get 'custom_action', on: :collection
end
```

first_models_controller.rb

```
class FirstModelsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    redirect_to controller: 'SecondModelsController', action: 'custom_action'
  end
end
```

second_models_controller.rb

```
class SecondModelsController < ApplicationController
  def custom_action
    # Do something
  end
end
```

After setting that up, navigating to /first_models/2 results in an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"custom_action", :controller=>"SecondModelsController", :id=>"2"}
```

I cannot figure out how to strip out the id param from the original request so that the routing matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that you call `redirect_to` with a Hash argument. Internally Rails uses `url_for` to build the final location, which in turn uses `default_url_options` which uses the ID of the current resource. From the API docs:

> Missing routes keys may be filled in from the current request's parameters (e.g. :controller, :action, :id and any other parameters that are placed in the path).

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html

**Solution:** Use a named path helper.

Run `bundle exec rake routes` on the command line to get a list of all your routes and named path helpers. Pick the one that you need and use it as follows:

`redirect_to my_named_path_helper_path`

Answer (score 1):

It is not the param the problem:

```
class FirstModelsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    redirect_to controller: 'second_models', action: 'custom_action'
  end
end
```

You can type rails routes and see all your routes and how rails recognize them.

This should work. However you can be more explicit and use:

```
redirect_to custom_action_second_models_path
```